# Issues with starting up discord bot using node.js

Tags: node.js, bots, discord.js

So I've been trying to help setup a bot for a discord server using node.js. My code seems to be just fine, and I've looked at videos and other resources for help, but whenever I try and start up the bot from my index.js file, nothing happens and it just stays offline. I've used "node ." and "node index.js" and nothing. I even went as far as to create another bot and follow the simple tutorials on youtube and the bot still wouldn't come online. Here is what I have for the simple bot which is just the copied version from the yt tutorials.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const TOKEN = "token_here";

const client = new Discord.Client();


client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("I'm online!")
});

client.login(TOKEN);
```

Comment: Do you use the valid token? Does `client` variable store anything after login attempt?

Comment: Yes, I just replaced it with 'token_here' as to not share my bot with anyone. As for the other question, I do not believe so

Comment: Are you getting any error(s) in the console?

Comment: No, when I say nothing I happens, I mean I get absolutely nothing from the console. No errors, no messages. The only time I got an error was when I miss typed indes.js instead of index.js

Comment: Yeah, @Jakye is right. I mean `client` stores some data by default. After the succesful login some changes occur. But do you have the error like  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid
token was provided ?

Comment: @David What versions of node.js and discord.js are you using?

Comment: For node.js I'm using v14.8.0 and for discord.js 12.3.1. Should I be using 12.18.3 for node.js instead?

Comment: I would suggest you to use the LTS version of node.js (currently 12.18.3) to just check whether it's not a node.js - discord.js incompatibility issue. I am confused that your event listener isn't fired and you also don't get the error, that's really strange.

Comment: @HlibDerbenov Well, I tried using the LTS version and still nothing happened. No message, no error, and the bot still is offline. Is it possibly something I did wrong in setting up everything? Because I did do npm init

Comment: @David That's what I think: there's a need to check all steps: discord.js installed (node_modules), correct file (script) is started (index.js as you say), working terminal is active (e.g. just use the console.log somewhere in code). Discord docs say there shouldn't be this behaviour as you have with your project...